# why doesnt the sign flag get set after this instruction execution?

Tags: assembly, x86, flags, signed

im playing with some instructions in 8086 assembly,and im wondering why the SF flag doesnt set even though the MSB of the result is a 1.

my code is :

```
 mov al,-48
  
 mov bl,4

 imul bl
```

the result that gets stored in AX is FF40H,the flags that get set are:

CF=1

OF=1

SF=0

why is the SF still at 0 even though the result is negative? and the MSB is also 1?

Answer (score 3):

For this particular instruction, the sign flag is not set.

https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul

Look also in the  [Intel Software Development Manual Vol 1](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/671200) table A-2

Comment: To be more specific, the value of SF will be undefined.